# CustomPaint and FittedBox

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

how to fit my CustomPaint to parent widget?

```
return new Container(
    color: Color(0xfffff4f0),
    child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  child: widget CustomePaint() // Containers(),

          )),
          new Expanded(
              flex: 4,
          )
    )
)
```

fit: BoxFit.contain works for

```
    Container(
        height: 30,
        width: 10
    )
```

but not work with CustomePaint() where i draw on canvas rectangle:

```
canvas.drawRect(new Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 10 , 30), new Paint()..color = 
Colors.red);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've provided just a part of code needed.

I've tried almost your's code and it worked just fine. I've used another colors and added a border to CustomPaint to better see where it is drawn.

```
Widget getRootView() {
  return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: CustomPaint(painter: Painter3()),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(child: Text("3")),
          ),
        )
      ]));
}

class Painter3 extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(Offset(10, 10) & Size(size.width - 20, size.height - 20), Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

What I'v get here is: [image: The result of the code above]